# There are some tables not exported when I export the database from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I export the SQL DB from PHPMyAdmin, the SQL exported file doesn't contain all the tables

Answer (score 0):

Try to export with Custom - display all possible options

here are the steps:

1)Export

2)Export method:=Custom - display all possible options

3)Select Tables: select all the tables

[image: check here]